# Why am I getting ObjCClassNotFoundException: GADInterstitial in RoboVM?

Tags: ios, admob, robovm

I am implementing admob in my iOS module using [this guide.](https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods/tree/master/google-mobile-ads/ios#display-ads)

I have a view controller where my interstitial ads are initialized like this

```
@CustomClass
public class ViewController extends UIViewController implements ActionResolver {

private GADInterstitial interstitial;

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX";

public ViewController() {
    viewDidLoad();
}

@Override
public void viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial();
}

private GADInterstitial createAndLoadInterstitial() {
    //Ad Unit ID of your interstital, from adMob account.
    GADInterstitial interstitial = new GADInterstitial(AD_UNIT_ID);
    System.out.println("Add unit ID is " + AD_UNIT_ID);
    interstitial.setDelegate(new GADInterstitialDelegateAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void didDismissScreen(GADInterstitial ad) {
            ViewController.this.interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial();
        }
    });
    interstitial.loadRequest(createRequest());
    return interstitial;
}

private GADRequest createRequest() {
    GADRequest request = new GADRequest();
    // To test on your devices, add their UDIDs here:
    request.setTestDevices(Arrays.asList(GADRequest.getSimulatorID()));
    return request;
}

@IBAction
public void showInterstitialAd() {
    if (interstitial.isReady()) {
        interstitial.present(UIApplication.getSharedApplication().getKeyWindow().getRootViewController());
        System.out.println("Interstitial is loaded.");
    } else {
        interstitial.loadRequest(createRequest());
        System.out.println("Interstitial not ready!");
    }
}
```

}

My implementation is similar to [this guide](https://upandcrawling.wordpress.com/2016/01/02/libgdx-and-google-mobile-ads-robopods-integration-ios/#comment-167) also.

When I run my app on the simulator I get the following exception.

```
org.robovm.objc.ObjCClassNotFoundException: GADInterstitial
at org.robovm.objc.ObjCClass.getByType(ObjCClass.java:251)
at org.robovm.objc.ObjCClass.getFromObject(ObjCClass.java:212)
at org.robovm.objc.ObjCObject.getObjCClass(ObjCObject.java:161)
at org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSObject.alloc(NSObject.java:214)
at org.robovm.objc.ObjCObject.<init>(ObjCObject.java:79)
at org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSObject.<init>(NSObject.java:157)
at org.robovm.pods.google.mobileads.GADInterstitial.<init>(GADInterstitial.java:52)
at com.nauv.fut.simulator.ViewController.createAndLoadInterstitial(ViewController.java:39)
at com.nauv.fut.simulator.ViewController.viewDidLoad(ViewController.java:34)
at com.nauv.fut.simulator.ViewController.<init>(ViewController.java:27)
at com.nauv.fut.simulator.IOSLauncher.createApplication(IOSLauncher.java:30)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication$Delegate.didFinishLaunching(IOSApplication.java:65)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication$Delegate.$cb$application$didFinishLaunchingWithOptions$(IOSApplication.java)
at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:413)
at com.nauv.fut.simulator.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java:35)
```

I have imported the admob framework on my ios build.gradle. I have also tried moving it to ios module in main build.gradle though this doesnt change anything. How can I fix this error? My class is being imported correctly and I am using `project.ext.robopodsVersion = "1.14.0"` on my app build.gradle.

Comment: Have the same issue...No luck so far

Comment: @SAKIROGLUKoray considering robovm is no longer supported, I dont think this bug will be solved.

Comment: Found a working solution below :)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately some people forked the project and I have found a working solution :)

The fork : https://github.com/MobiDevelop/robovm-robopods

I did the following.

Gradle:

**Build script dependency**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

**IOS Project dependencies:**

```
...
compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-parent:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Download SDK from [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download)

Copy the GoogleMobileAds.framework folder in ios/libs

**Modify the robovm.xml file** (I went completely overkill on the frameworks list but I was tired of compilation error, if you find the ones that are not necessary, feel free to let me know):

```
<config>
    ...
    <frameworkPaths>
        <path>libs</path>
    </frameworkPaths>
    <frameworks>
        <framework>UIKit</framework>
        <framework>OpenGLES</framework>
        <framework>QuartzCore</framework>
        <framework>CoreGraphics</framework>
        <framework>OpenAL</framework>
        <framework>AudioToolbox</framework>
        <framework>AVFoundation</framework>
        <framework>AdSupport</framework>
        <framework>AudioToolbox</framework>
        <framework>CoreMedia</framework>
        <framework>CoreMotion</framework>
        <framework>CoreVideo</framework>
        <framework>CoreTelephony</framework>
        <framework>CoreBluetooth</framework>
        <framework>SafariServices</framework>
        <framework>EventKit</framework>
        <framework>EventKitUI</framework>
        <framework>MediaPlayer</framework>
        <framework>MessageUI</framework>
        <framework>StoreKit</framework>
        <framework>SystemConfiguration</framework>
        <framework>GoogleMobileAds</framework>
        <framework>VideoToolbox</framework>
        <framework>GLKit</framework>
    </frameworks>
</config>
```

And this works (for me)